# Simple Neural Network visualisation

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I was wondering if someone could help me about visualising neurons going off in a neural network while it is training. I very much would like to do this, and have found nothing on google yet that visualises the neurons in the sense that I mean. What I am picturing is a simple cmd window with a block of spaces alternating between white and black, like when you select in cmd by holding left click. I saw this on a twitch stream where you could see this going on as a deep learning project was drawing pages of DBZ comics or something, and I believe it was described as showing which neuron was being activated at which moment. If anybody had any ideas I would greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score -1):

please take a look at [tensor board](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard), it includes neuron learning visualization.

Here is [medium blog](https://medium.com/@awjuliani/visualizing-neural-network-layer-activation-tensorflow-tutorial-d45f8bf7bbc4) that shows some examples.